# Use jQuery data() or attr() be used when value is originally written by the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using PHP, I write some HTML to the page:

```
echo("<span id='myID' data-id='{$someValue}'>Hello</span>");
```

Then, later, I change the value of `data-id` using jQuery.

Then, even later, I use jQuery to get the value of `data-id` and use ajax to send to the server.

My question is should I use `attr()` or `data()`?  Note my value is always a string or integer, and not an object.  For instance....

```
$('#myID').attr('data-id',321);
var id=$('#myID').attr('data-id');

/or

$('#myID').data('id',321);
var id=$('#myID').data('id');
```

Comment: When you change the value using jQuery, which command do you use?

Comment: @Blazemonger Do you know which version they changed to read `data-id` attribute using `.data` function?

Comment: @Vega [Looks like I had it backwards](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/bGEgv/). `.data('id')` pulls the `data-` attribute value in just once on page load, and only once. Perhaps old versions of jQuery did it every time.

Comment: @Sirko Either `$('#myID').attr('data-id',321);` or `$('#myID').data('id',321);`.  Thus the question.

Comment: @user1032531 The difference is important: Whereas `attr()` changes the DOM element, `data()` just changes jQuery's data object associated to that DOM element. `data()` just *initializes*  the data object according to the DOM object. All changes thereafter are not reflected!

Comment: @Sirko. Thanks.  I had figured that out earlier.  Do you agree with Snuffleupagus that future changes should be done using `data()`?

Comment: @user1032531 Make sure to change all `attr('data-')` to the `data()` functions, so you have a unified approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data`. No point in manipulating the DOM if you don't need to.

Comment: Thanks Snuffleupagus.  I usually do so, but sometimes troubleshooting using FireBug is more difficult since I can see the attribute value change.